# HighScore list gui problem

Tags: android

I implemented a highscore list with a table, however this is cumbersome since all TextViews have their own id etc. Is there a widget/control which is more suitable for this purpose? I wanna show two columns. Both columns should have their column header.

Can you give me some recommendations on how to make this really an Android thingy?

Help is very much appreciated.

Jasper

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ListView`, supplying an `ArrayAdapter` set up to turn your high scores into list rows. If you want your header to scroll with the list contents, call `addHeaderView()` to add it to the `ListView`. If you want your header to not scroll with the list contents, draw it above the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

For highscoring, I strongly advise you have a look at [ScoreNinja](http://scoreninja.appspot.com/) which you may find does much of the hard work for you.